# Javascript Injection with PYthon

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, url, javascript-injection

I am attempting to use python to open up web pages, and the perform a javascript injection. The goal is to actually change the values of some forms (ex: putting data into a form) Currently the test program that I have written for opening up a page is:

```
import urllib2 as u
f = u.urlopen("http://www.google.com")
print f.read()
f.close()
```

So now what I was thinking for the injection (in this case printing Hello world)

```
import urllib2 as u
f = u.urlopen("http://www.google.com/javascript:alert(\" hello world \")")
print f.read()
f.close()
```

But when I run the code I recieve the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Sid\Rutgers\3 Semester\HackHerz\ChalupaCity\Sid\thefile.py", line 12, in <module>
    f = u.urlopen("http://www.google.com/javascript:alert(\" hello world \")")
  File "c:\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "c:\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 410, in open response = meth(req, response)
  File "c:\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "c:\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "c:\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "c:\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

So i decided to explore a bit. And I discovered that python is probably going to the URL of the name

```
http://www.google.com/javascript:alert(\" hello world \")
```

So I tried to separate into two lines

```
f = u.urlopen("http://www.google.com/")

f.urlopen("javascript:alert(\" hello world \")")
print f.read()
f.close()
```

But that doesn't work either.

How to go through with this? Ultimately I want to be able to change form data with Javascript.

Comment: That's... not how JavaScript injection works...

Comment: In google chrome I just type javascript:(followed by my code), so I was wondering if it was a similar process

Comment: @downvoter, please explain? I explained what I was trying to do, I showed work, and I gave my hypothesis, what else can you downvote this for?

Comment: @frogeyedpeas There's no *browser* involved. In the case of typical web browsers such as Chrome and Firefox, there are multiple steps involved, including downloading the page, parsing the content, running the JavaScript code and displaying it all on screen. In the case of `urlopen`, only the download step is done, thus Python does not know how to interpret your JavaScript code.

Comment: @Frxstrem , what sort of tool would be used then to run Javascript code from python?

Comment: Not sure what you're going for here exactly but sounds to me more like you want to modify the HTTP headers with the desired post data for your form, no need to execute java script..

Comment: @GmanO ultimately I want to open an html page, put data into a form, and post the form and see how the page changes

Comment: @frogeyedpeas I personally haven't done this myself but think about using beautiful soup with a parser to extract all form field text and store as variables in python. Then modify those vars to your liking. Then build a new HTTP response header. One could possibly even use urllib to post, something like: params = urllib.urlencode(values)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Possibly using [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)?

You may also wish to look into urllib2 module or [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) library to assist you.

Or you could try updating the HTTP headers with the desired post data before you reply to the server.

Good luck!